# Getting IllegalStateException while calling restTemplate.exchange()

Tags: java, json, file, resttemplate

Getting the `java.lang.IllegalStateException` while trying to read the data from json file using `RestTemplate.exchange()`. Tried many ways, but no success. Any suggestion would be appreciate.

Code:

```
ResponseEntity<GetCustomerResponse> customerResponse = restTemplate.exchange("J:\Backup\FILWORKSPACE\tapp100997_accountopeningservice\target\classes\testdata\CustomerEnquiryApiResponse.json",HttpMethod.POST, request, GetCustomerResponse.class);
```

Exception :

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create URI object: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: J:\Backup\FILWORKSPACE\tapp100997_accountopeningservice\target\classes\testdata\CustomerEnquiryApiResponse.json
    at org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriTemplateHandler.createUri(DefaultUriTemplateHandler.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriTemplateHandler.expandInternal(DefaultUriTemplateHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.util.AbstractUriTemplateHandler.expand(AbstractUriTemplateHandler.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:612)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at com.fidintl.bs.accountopening.rulengine.rules.CustomerRule.getCustomerDetails(CustomerRule.java:169)
    at com.fidintl.bs.accountopening.rulengine.rules.CustomerRule.execute(CustomerRule.java:55)
    at com.fidintl.bs.accountopening.rulengine.rules.CustomerRuleTest.testCustomerEligibilityWithBlankData(CustomerRuleTest.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: J:\Backup\FILWORKSPACE\tapp100997_accountopeningservice\target\classes\testdata\CustomerEnquiryApiResponse.json
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3058)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriTemplateHandler.createUri(DefaultUriTemplateHandler.java:165)
    ... 33 more
```

Json file Data :

```
 {"success":true,"errors":[],"customerDetails":[{"customerReference":{"type":"PARTY_REFERENCE_NUMBER","identifier":"500008713684"},"success":true,"errors":[],"customers":[{"customerType":"INDIVIDUAL_INVESTOR","individualClientDetails":{"personalDetails":{"personName":{"title":"Miss","initials":null,"firstName":"User","lastName":"Payroll","fullName":"Miss User Payroll","printName":"Miss User Payroll"},"dateOfBirth":"1970-12-01","dateOfDeath":null,"gender":"UNKNOWN","maritalStatus":"UNKNOWN","townOfBirth":null,"countryOfBirth":"GB","nationalityDetails":[{"countryCode":"GB","primaryNationalityFlag":null,"reportingNationalityFlag":"Y","reportingDetails":{"nationalIdType":"TAX_IDENTIFIER","nationalId":"AB109999D"}},{"countryCode":"GB","primaryNationalityFlag":"Y","reportingNationalityFlag":null,"reportingDetails":null}],"countriesOfResidence":[{"countryCode":"GB","countryName":"UNITED KINGDOM","primaryCountryOfResidence":"Y"}],"age":"48","niNoIssuedFlag":"Y","anticipatedRetirementAge":null},"crownEmployeeFlag":"N","planParticipantDetails":null,"employerDetails":null,"occupation":null},"institutionalClientDetails":null,"partyReferenceNumber":"500008713684","alternativeReferences":[{"identifierType":"SONATA_CLIENT_ID","identifier":"100668431"},{"identifierType":"INVESTOR_REFERENCE_NUMBER","identifier":"1004664408"}],"lifeCycleStatus":"INVESTOR","inceptionDate":"2019-03-19","dormancyDate":null,"directAdvisedIndicator":"DIRECT_AND_ADVISED","lostContactFlag":"N","probateFlag":"N","courtOfProtectionFlag":"N","languagePreference":"ENG","postalAddresses":[{"contactRole":"CORRESPONDENCE_ADDRESS","nonStructuredAddressDetails":{"line1":"30 Benedict Drive","line2":null,"line3":"FELTHAM","line4":null},"structuredAddressDetails":null,"overrideAddress":"N","administrativeArea":null,"postalTown":"FELTHAM","postalCode":"TW14 8JL","region":"UK","countryCode":"GB","setBy":"500008713684","status":"ACTIVE","validity":{"lastValidatedDate":null,"validFrom":"2019-03-19 18:05:07.000+0000","validTo":null},"countryName":"UNITED KINGDOM"},{"contactRole":"REGISTERED_ADDRESS","nonStructuredAddressDetails":{"line1":"30 Benedict Drive","line2":null,"line3":"FELTHAM","line4":null},"structuredAddressDetails":null,"overrideAddress":"N","administrativeArea":null,"postalTown":"FELTHAM","postalCode":"TW14 8JL","region":"UK","countryCode":"GB","setBy":"500008713684","status":"ACTIVE","validity":{"lastValidatedDate":null,"validFrom":"2019-03-19 18:05:07.000+0000","validTo":null},"countryName":"UNITED KINGDOM"}],"classifications":[{"classificationScheme":"FATCA_US","classificationCode":"INUS05","classificationDescription":"Non US Status"},{"classificationScheme":"OFFICE_CODE","classificationCode":"OAKH","classificationDescription":"FIL Investments International"},{"classificationScheme":"MIFID","classificationCode":"RE","classificationDescription":"Retail"},{"classificationScheme":"GFAS_CUSTOMER_TYPE","classificationCode":"P","classificationDescription":"Private Individual"}],"externalIdentifiers":[{"identifierName":"TAX_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER","value":"AB109999D","country":"GB","tinNotIssued":"NOT_CONFIRMED"},{"identifierName":"NATIONAL_INSURANCE_NUMBER","value":"AB109999D","country":"GB","tinNotIssued":null}],"salutations":null,"documentDeliveryPreferenceDetails":{"documentDeliveryPreferences":[{"documentType":"COT","deliveryMethod":"POST_AND_ONLINE"},{"documentType":"SAV","deliveryMethod":"POST_AND_ONLINE"},{"documentType":"PLC","deliveryMethod":"POST_AND_ONLINE"},{"documentType":"RRL","deliveryMethod":"POST_AND_ONLINE"},{"documentType":"WPL","deliveryMethod":"POST_AND_ONLINE"},{"documentType":"DTL","deliveryMethod":"POST_AND_ONLINE"},{"documentType":"ITR","deliveryMethod":"POST_AND_ONLINE"},{"documentType":"WL","deliveryMethod":"POST_AND_ONLINE"},{"documentType":"MLC","deliveryMethod":"POST_AND_ONLINE"}],"emailNotificationFlag":"N"},"electronicAddresses":null,"telephones":null,"partyAssociations":null,"amlStatusDetails":null,"bankAccountDetails":null,"w8BenDetails":null,"reportingCurrency":null,"associatedFILEmployee":null,"employmentStatus":null,"marketingSource":null,"partyGenericVariables":{"genericVariables":[{"name":"PLATFORM","values":["SONATA"]},{"name":"PDP_CONSENT","values":["YES"]}]},"restrictions":null,"roleToFIL":null,"marketingPreferences":[],"applicationTerms":[{"applicationTermsAndCondition":{"applicationName":"ISA Declaration","applicationVersion":"1.0","applicationTermsAndConditionsVersion":"2.0","dateAccepted":"2015-03-12 00:00:00.000+0000","applicationType":"DOCUMENT"}},{"applicationTermsAndCondition":{"applicationName":"Doing Business with Fidelity","applicationVersion":"1.0","applicationTermsAndConditionsVersion":"2.0","dateAccepted":"2015-03-12 00:00:00.000+0000","applicationType":"DOCUMENT"}},{"applicationTermsAndCondition":{"applicationName":"Payroll ISA","applicationVersion":"1.0","applicationTermsAndConditionsVersion":"2.0","dateAccepted":"2015-03-12 00:00:00.000+0000","applicationType":"DOCUMENT"}},{"applicationTermsAndCondition":{"applicationName":"Fidelity's Privacy Policy","applicationVersion":"1.0","applicationTermsAndConditionsVersion":"2.0","dateAccepted":"2015-03-12 00:00:00.000+0000","applicationType":"DOCUMENT"}},{"applicationTermsAndCondition":{"applicationName":"US Person","applicationVersion":"1.0","applicationTermsAndConditionsVersion":"2.0","dateAccepted":"2015-03-12 00:00:00.000+0000","applicationType":"DOCUMENT"}},{"applicationTermsAndCondition":{"applicationName":"Client Terms","applicationVersion":"1.0","applicationTermsAndConditionsVersion":"2.0","dateAccepted":"2015-03-12 00:00:00.000+0000","applicationType":"DOCUMENT"}},{"applicationTermsAndCondition":{"applicationName":"Online Terms","applicationVersion":"1.0","applicationTermsAndConditionsVersion":"2.0","dateAccepted":"2015-03-12 00:00:00.000+0000","applicationType":"DOCUMENT"}}],"createdBy":null,"assignedTo":null,"updatedBy":null,"auditDetails":null,"standingPreferences":null,"literaturePreferences":null,"documentDeliveryPreferences":null,"pensionDetails":null,"migration":null,"pensionPlatform":null,"clientRegionDetails":null}]}]}
```

Comment: Can you show JSON data and full stacktrace?

Comment: ok @Elgin . updating the question with required details.

Comment: @Elgin, any suggestion ?

Comment: Why do you want to read a file with rest template?

Comment: @MartinTarjányi , actually I am trying to Mock the method(execute) which is using resttemplate.exchange. So, I am providing the complete path of json file in my test case like following:

Comment: File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(Constants.CUSTOMER_ENQUIRY_TEST_DATA).getFile());
  CUSTOMER_API_URL = file.getAbsolutePath();
  ruleArgument.addArgument(Constants.ACCOUNT, account);
  ruleArgument.addArgument(Constants.API_TOKEN, apiToken);
ruleArgument.addArgument(Constants.REST_TEMPLATE,restTemplate);
  ruleArgument.addArgument(Constants.CUSTOMER_API_URL, CUSTOMER_API_URL);
  
  Result ruleResult =customerRule.execute(ruleArgument);

Comment: @rawat0157 take a look at wiremock for mocking http: http://wiremock.org/ it starts up a mock http server in which you can stub your data

Comment: Need to use only Mockito, but didn't work anything.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-restful/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/

Answer (score 0):

From docs https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-,

> Execute the HTTP method to the given URI template, writing the given request entity to the request, and returns the response as ResponseEntity.

You need to use valid hhtp url.

Comment: Already tried with this solution, was getting following exception.       org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://file/J:/Backup/FILWORKSPACE/tapp100997_accountopeningservice/target/classes/testdata/CustomerEnquiryApiResponse.json": file; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: file